# ggplot: transperancy of histogram as function of stat(count)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a scaled histogram in a such a way, that transparency of each "column" (bin?) depends on the number of observations in a given range of x. Here is my code:

```
set.seed(1)
test = data.frame(x = rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = 10),
                  y = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)))
threshold = 20 
ggplot(test,
       aes(x = x))+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = y, alpha = stat(count) > threshold),
                 position = "fill", bins = 10)
```

Basically I want to make plots that will looks like this:

[image]

however my code generate the plots there transparency are applied based on the count after grouping that ends up with hanging column like this:

[image]

For this example, in order to simulate a "proper" plot I just adjust the threshold, but I need alpha to consider sum of count from both groups in a given "column"(bin).

**UPDATE:**
I also want it to work with faceted plots in a such a way that highlighted area in each facet was independent from other facets. Approach that proposed @Stefan works perfect for the individual plot, but in faceted plot highlights the same area at all facets.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
test = data.frame(x = rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 10),
                  y = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=1000)),
                  n = as.factor(sample(c(0,1,2), replace=TRUE, size=1000)),
                  m = as.factor(sample(c(0,1,3,4), replace=TRUE, size=1000)))
f = function(..count.., ..x..) tapply(..count.., factor(..x..), sum)[factor(..x..)]
threshold = 10 
ggplot(test,
       aes(x = x))+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = y, alpha = f(..count.., ..x..) > threshold),
                 position = "fill", bins = 10)+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(n),
             cols = vars(m))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. As the `count` computed by `stat_count` is the number of obs after grouping we have to manually aggregate the `count` over groups to get the total `count` per bin.
2. To aggregate the counts per bin I use `tapply`, where I make use of the `..` notation to get the variables computed by `stat_count`.
3. As the grouping variable I make use of the computed variable **`..x..` which to the best of my knowledge is not documented**. Basically `..x..` contains by default the midpoints of the bins and as such can be used as an identifier for the bins. However, as these are continuous values we have convert them to a factor.

Finally, to make the code more readable I use a auxilliary function to compute the aggregate counts. Additionally I double the `threshold` value to 20.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = 10),
  y = as.factor(sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 100))
)
threshold <- 20

f <- function(..count.., ..x..) tapply(..count.., factor(..x..), sum)[factor(..x..)]
p <- ggplot(
  test,
  aes(x = x)
) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = y, alpha = f(..count.., ..x..) > threshold),
    position = "fill", bins = 10
  )
p
```

[image]

**EDIT** To allow for facetting we have to pass the function the `..PANEL..` identifier as an addtional argument. Instead of using `tapply` I now use `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::add_count` to compute the total count per bin and facet panel:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = 10),
  y = as.factor(sample(c(0, 1), replace = TRUE, size = 100)),
  type = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 100)
)
threshold <- 20

f <- function(count, x, PANEL) {
  data.frame(count, x, PANEL) %>% 
    add_count(x, PANEL, wt = count) %>% 
    pull(n)
}
p <- ggplot(
  test,
  aes(x = x)
) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = y, alpha = f(..count.., ..x.., ..PANEL..) > threshold),
                 position = "fill", bins = 10
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~type)
p
#> Warning: Using alpha for a discrete variable is not advised.
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. Your solution perfectly works for the described example. However now I tried to faceted my plot and, of course, the same area is highlighted in each facet. Do you have an idea how to apply the function after data is split in facets or upgrade the function such as it can consider facets?

Comment: Hi Oleg. You are welcome. I just made an edit to (hopefully (;) allow for facetting. Check it out and tell me if it works.